# Why does the width of adaptive cards in Microsoft Teams squish the message horizontally

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

When posting adaptive cards to Microsoft Teams from Flow, the message appears to be squished to about 50% width.  It doesn't expand to fit the message container in Teams.

[Squished Adaptive Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IuqN.png)

Answer (score 4):

The "Full Width" Adaptive Card functionality was released at some point and is now available.

Microsoft has documentented how it works:

> ### [Constructing full width cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#full-width-adaptive-card)
>
> To make a full width Adaptive card the
> width object in `msteams` property in the card content must be set to
> Full. In addition, your app must include the following elements:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [{
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [{
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Digest card",
            "size": "Large",
            "weight": "Bolder"
        }]
    }],

    "msteams": {
        "width": "Full"
    },
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2"
}
```

Comment: this does not work when the card is part of a carousel

Answer (score 1):

Current behavior is by design, however we have backlog item to support full width adaptive card. I'll keep this thread updated.

Comment: Hi Nikitha, any update to support full width adaptive card on Microsoft Teams?

Comment: We are looking into it we don't have ETA to share when it will be available.

Comment: Can you please look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64480028/11844406) question?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT is there a scheduled date for this feature?

Comment: We are working on it. WE don't have ETA to share when it will be available.