# Adaptive Card: How to create table with 6 columns without truncating text?

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have created a adaptive card to show as table. But, the text is getting truncated like `Today I...` instead of `Today In Count` complete text.

This Adaptive card is for Microsoft Teams.

**Adaptive Card:**

```
{
   "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
   "type":"AdaptiveCard",
   "version":"1.2",
   "body":[
      {
         "type":"ColumnSet",
         "columns":[
            {
               "type":"Column",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"Zone",
                     "weight":"bolder"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"EAST ZONE",
                     "separator":true
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "type":"Column",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"Today In Counter",
                     "weight":"bolder"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"168",
                     "separator":true
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "type":"Column",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"Monthly Count (A)",
                     "weight":"bolder"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"5884",
                     "separator":true
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "type":"Column",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"Cancel (B)",
                     "weight":"bolder"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"1",
                     "separator":true
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "type":"Column",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"Return (C)",
                     "weight":"bolder"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"19",
                     "separator":true
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "type":"Column",
               "items":[
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"NET Re Count (A-B-C)",
                     "weight":"bolder"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"TextBlock",
                     "isSubtle":true,
                     "width":"stretch",
                     "text":"5864",
                     "separator":true
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

How to get complete text in all columns or How to increase width of column?

**Update-1:**

After changing `width: 'stretch'` to `width: 'auto'` in designer it working fine even after selecting `host app as Microsoft Teams`. But not working on actual teams application.

Any suggestions?

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way I can give column padding to an adaptive card- Adaptive MS BOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63122062/is-there-a-way-i-can-give-column-padding-to-an-adaptive-card-adaptive-ms-bot)

Comment: Please edit the Adaptive Card JSON in your question so that your Boolean values are lowercase (`true` instead of `True`) and so that all your text properties have string values (`"168"` instead of `168`, etc.). It currently will not render in the designer: https://adaptivecards.io/designer/

Comment: @KyleDelaney I have edited Adaptive Card JSON as you suggested. Can you please check and help?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Can you please check my updated question?

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible as Manish said, but if you're willing to use word wrap to make your items taller instead of wider then you should find everything you need to know in the question I linked to

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes, I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Are you willing to use word wrap to make your items taller instead of wider, and have you looked at the answer to the question I linked you to?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I have checked the above link. If I use `"wrap": true` the items look larger and I can able to see complete text. But, it doesn't look good as all columns are not in same margin. They are up and down. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: If you mean that the items are not aligned, i.e. there are no consistent "rows," then the solution is already in the other question. If that's not what you mean, can you edit your question to include screenshots of the actual problem you're seeing?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: @KyleDelaney No. `ColumnSet` for each row with `wrap:true` solved my problem. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot widen your Adaptive Cards like Manish said, you can wrap the text so that each cell becomes taller as needed. In order to format the cells into neat rows instead of just columns, you can use a separate column set for each row as explained in this answer: [Is there a way I can give column padding to an adaptive card- Adaptive MS BOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63122062/is-there-a-way-i-can-give-column-padding-to-an-adaptive-card-adaptive-ms-bot/63367728#63367728)

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive Cards have limited fixed width and aren't meant to display tabular layout which has more than 3 colums(again subject to column name). You can achieve this layouts with Task Module.Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules) documentation for more details.

Comment: Every card in MS Teams have fixed size and it can't exceed that. The above scenario can be achieved with the help of Task Modules in MS Teams.